# I'm getting the right answer but for some reason its outputting my user inputs as well I'm confused as to why

Tags: python

The following equation estimates the average calories burned for a person when exercising, which is based on a scientific journal article (source):

```
Calories = ( (Age * 0.2757) + (Weight * 0.03295) + (Heart Rate * 1.0781) - 75.4991 ) * Time / 8.368
```

Write a program using inputs age (years), weight (pounds), heart rate (beats per minute), and time (minutes), respectively. Output the average calories burned for a person.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows: `print('Calories: {:.2f} calories'.format(calories))`

---

THIS IS MY CODE:

```py
age_years = float(input("Age:"))
#this secures input from user for age in years

weight_lbs = float(input("Weight:"))
#this secures input from user for weight

heart_rate_bpm = float(input("Heart Rate:"))
#this secures heart rate from user 

time_min = float(input("Time:"))
#this secures the time of activity in minutes

calories = ((age_years * 0.2757) + (weight_lbs * 0.03295) + (heart_rate_bpm * 1.0781) - 75.4991) * time_min / 8.368
#this is the formula for figuring average calories burned based on input by user

print('Calories: {:.2f} calories'.format(calories))
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT I KEEP GETTING:

```
Age:Weight:Heart Rate:Time:Calories: 736.21 calories
```

Comment: It seems like whatever is grading your homework is using some form of non-standard input. Does it work as expected when you run it yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you run the program in order to get this result? In your own words, where the code says `float(input("Age:"))`, what do you think this means? In particular, what effect do you expect the `"Age:"` part of that code to have? Why? Do you see how that relates to the behaviour you are observing?

Comment: Karl I understand that input is what the computer asks the user to input to gather the needed information to compute calories. I expect the age as well as other input parameters to be printed out when asking user to input that info just not clear why it would print with my output?

Comment: I've run the code and it works just fine. I'm not getting the same output as you. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm doing it inside my online text book zybooks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you didn't add a print code after each calculation, so it's only printing calories. Conversely, if you want it to ONLY print calories, then removing the text that's within the quotes for the other input sections will allow only "Calories:" and the solution to be printed.

Sorry if my verbiage is incorrect, I just started my first Python course a few days ago.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
age_years = int(input())
#this secures input from user for age in years

weight_lbs = int(input())
#this secures input from user for weight

heart_rate_bpm = int(input())
#this secures heart rate from user 

time_min = int(input())
#this secures the time of activity in minutes

calories = ((age_years * 0.2757) + (weight_lbs * 0.03295) + (heart_rate_bpm * 1.0781) - 75.4991) * time_min / 8.368
#this is the formula for figuring average calories burned based on input by user

print('Calories: {:.2f} calories'.format(calories))
```

Answer (score 0):

age_years = int(input())

weight_lbs = int(input())

heart_rate_bpm = int(input())
#this secures heart rate from user

time_min = int(input())
#this secures the time of activity in minutes

calories = ((age_years * 0.2757) + (weight_lbs * 0.03295) + (heart_rate_bpm * 1.0781) - 75.4991) * time_min / 8.368
#this is the formula for figuring average calories burned based on input by user

print('Calories: {:.2f} calories'.format(calories))

I found in your solution where the calories are you put format before the calories, it only wanted that one line, and it ran the code for me, im also working in zybooks, the expected output was looking for just that code